# how to apply same filter to multiple dataframes

Tags: python, list, dataframe

How can I filter the list of dataframes with the same column category in one code?

```
filter_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

for name in filter_list:
     name.columns[columns['category'] == 'category1']
```

Comment: name[name["category"]=="category"]]

Comment: you mean 
for name in filter_list:
     name.name[name["category"]=="category"]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a method that has an `inplace` argument for the assignment in a `for` loop.

I will demonstrate with dropping everything where `category` *does not* equal `category1`

```py
filter_list = [df1,df2,df3,df4]

for x in filter_list:
    x.drop(x[x['category']!='category1'].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: How can I try with pd.DataFrame.query()? I just want to know for my knowledge

Comment: I edited that out of my response because `query()` uses a string to do the query itself, and the string doesn't update based on the iterable. `query1 = df['cat']=='cat1' 
  df.query('@query1', inplace=True)` works, but if you try to change the query1 to say `x['cat']=='cat1'` you get an index error because x (the iterable variable in for loop) doesnt actually exist.